# How can nmp run build work when deploying vue app with asp.net core 3 on azure

Tags: azure, vue.js, deployment, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.1

am triying to deploy my vue asp.net core 3 app on ,azure , I can't publish my app through Visual Studio and I can't NPM run build and move it to IIS any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using https://blog.bitsrc.io/getting-started-with-vue-js-in-net-core-using-visual-studio-efbb43703630 as a starting point, I didn't encounter any issues when publishing the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/esausilva/vuejs-aspnet-core) to an Azure App Service, as shown below.

[image]

Since the VueJs is within a .NETCORE app, I did opt for a Linux App Service plan, which meant a longer startup time as the base images were being pulled. You didn't specify what errors you had but a simple `git clone`, `npm i`, F5 to make sure the app ran; I created the publish profile within Visual Studio and published. The publish profile should set the startup command of the app service to `dotnet <your-project>.dll`

[image]